# Android use vector drawable to replace text in button

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

Currently I have a button that looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to be able to replace the text with this vector drawable but keep the blue rectangle background:

[image]

I looked into doing this but I cannot seem to get it right.

I tried the following combination:

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/deletebutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/deletebtn24dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primaryButtonColor"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

However that just led to a blank blue button with no drawable. What can I do so the drawable replaces the text?

Also I would like to support API levels start at 16+.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `app:srcCompat="@drawable/deletebtn24dp"` instead of `android:src="@drawable/deletebtn24dp"`. Using an `ImageButton` might also be better than using a straight `Button`.